# Update MySQL table with php Array don't works

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Hey guys I need your help, I have this table [FIDDLE](http://fiddle.jshell.net/MetCastle/c38Da/) with inputs inside the td's with the same names that you can see, and I want to update some table but don't works, this is my code:

```
$CA_id = $_POST['CA_id'];   

$i = 1;
while (isset($_POST["item_id$i"])) {
    $item_id = $_POST["item_id$i"];
    $j = 1;
    while (isset($_POST["item_Cant$i$j"])) {

        $item_Cant = intval($_POST["item_Cant$i$j"]);
        $CECO_cod = intval($_POST["CECO_cod$i$j"]);
        $item_desc = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["item_desc$i$j"]);
        $item_enduser = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["item_enduser$i$j"]);

        $query = "
            UPDATE
                items
            SET  
                item_Cant = '$item_Cant',
                CECO_cod = '$CECO_cod',
                item_desc = '$item_desc',
                item_enduser = '$item_enduser' 
            WHERE 
                CA_id = $CA_id
                AND item_id = $item_id
        ";

        mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        $j++;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

I hope you understand and you can help me to fix my code, thanks.

Solution:

I just change

```
      echo "\t\t<tr class=\"row$r\">
                    <td><input readonly name= 'item_id".$a."' value='".htmlentities($row['item_id'])."'/></td>
                    <td><input name= 'item_Cant".$a."1' value='".htmlentities($row['item_Cant'])."'/></td>
                    <td><input name= 'CECO_cod".$a."2' value='".htmlentities($row['CECO_cod'])."'/></td>
                    <td><input name= 'item_desc".$a."3' value='".$row['item_desc']."'/></td>
                    <td><input name= 'item_enduser".$a."4' value='".$row['item_enduser']."'/></td>
                </tr>\n";
```

For this:

```
      echo "\t\t<tr class=\"row$r\">
                    <td><input readonly name= 'item_id".$a."' value='".htmlentities($row['item_id'])."'/></td>
                    <td><input name= 'item_Cant".$a."1' value='".htmlentities($row['item_Cant'])."'/></td>
                    <td><input name= 'CECO_cod".$a."1' value='".htmlentities($row['CECO_cod'])."'/></td>
                    <td><input name= 'item_desc".$a."1' value='".$row['item_desc']."'/></td>
                    <td><input name= 'item_enduser".$a."1' value='".$row['item_enduser']."'/></td>
                </tr>\n";
```

And now works like a charm ! Thanks to all !

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: Follow @Fred-ii- suggestion, because without the error, we can't help you.

Comment: Done, but when the form is submitted don't shows anything, just send the mail and redirect but nothing about error reporting, and other query below of the first update works fine 
`$query = "UPDATE compras_activos SET  STAT_name =  'Aprobado' WHERE  CA_id = '$CA_id'";`

I'm sure something in my code is wrong, I mean the array update from this post.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I edited my code with the solution, i just edited the numbers in input names [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/MetCastle/c38Da/) Now works fine :D Thanks

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are making life VERY difficult for yourself.

If you create the form using Field arrays like so :-

```
<table width="400" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="" name="item_id[]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="" name="item_Cant[]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="" name="CECO_cod[]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="" name="item_desc[]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="" name="item_enduser[]"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="" name="item_id[]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="" name="item_Cant[]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="" name="CECO_cod[]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="" name="item_desc[]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="" name="item_enduser[]"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="" name="item_id[]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="" name="item_Cant[]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="" name="CECO_cod[]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="" name="item_desc[]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="" name="item_enduser[]"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="" name="item_id[]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="" name="item_Cant[]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="" name="CECO_cod[]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="" name="item_desc[]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="" name="item_enduser[]"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="" name="item_id[]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="" name="item_Cant[]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="" name="CECO_cod[]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="" name="item_desc[]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="" name="item_enduser[]"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="" name="item_id[]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="" name="item_Cant[]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="" name="CECO_cod[]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="" name="item_desc[]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="" name="item_enduser[]"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

There are many benefits to this, you can `foreach` over the arrays, you dont need to use complex 2 level for loops, if you want to add a row its simple etc.

So now your code would look something like this :-

```
$CA_id = $_POST['CA_id'];   

foreach( $_POST['item_id'] as $idx => $item_id ) {
    if ( isset($_POST['item_Cant'][$idx]) ) {

        $item_Cant = intval($_POST["item_Cant"][$idx]);
        $CECO_cod = intval($_POST["CECO_cod"][$idx]);
        $item_desc = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["item_desc"][$idx]);
        $item_enduser = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["item_enduser"][$idx]);

        $query = "
        UPDATE
            items
        SET  
            item_Cant = '$item_Cant',
            CECO_cod = '$CECO_cod',
            item_desc = '$item_desc',
            item_enduser = '$item_enduser' 
        WHERE 
            CA_id = $CA_id
            AND item_id = $item_id
        ";

        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if ( ! $result ) {
            // then you have an error, report it somehow
            echo 'UPDATE FAILED: ';
            echo 'Error code: ' . mysql_errno(); . ' Error Desc : ' . mysql_error() . '<br>';
            echo $query . '<br>';
     }
 }
```

PS: You should really be using the mysqli_* or PDO extensions and not the mysql_* ones as they are deprecated and may be removed from PHP sometime soon.

Comment: Thanks man, I will change soon for mysqli_ , thanks so much for your answer !